# Ruby/Rails 3.1: Given a URL string, remove path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Given any valid HTTP/HTTPS string, I would like to parse/transform it such that the end result is exactly the root of the string.

So given URLs:

```
http://foo.example.com:8080/whatsit/foo.bar?x=y
https://example.net/
```

I would like the results:

```
http://foo.example.com:8080/
https://example.net/
```

I found the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/Parser.html) for URI::Parser not super approachable.

My initial, naïve solution would be a simple regex like:

```
/\A(https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/)/
```

(That is: Match up to the first slash after the protocol.)

Thoughts & solutions welcome. And apologies if this is a duplicate, but my search results weren't relevant.

Comment: And lest anyone be tempted to use my naïve “solution” above — please note it fails to match URLs that omit the trailing slash when there is no path, that is, `http://example.com` instead of `http://example.com/`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With [URI::join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-join):

```
require 'uri'
url = "http://foo.example.com:8080/whatsit/foo.bar?x=y"
baseurl = URI.join(url, "/").to_s
#=> "http://foo.example.com:8080/"
```

Comment: I really like this answer. It seems obvious in hindsight. `URI.join` is the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Use [`URI.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M009387) and then set the `path` to an empty string and the `query` to `nil`:

```
require 'uri'
uri     = URI.parse('http://foo.example.com:8080/whatsit/foo.bar?x=y')
uri.path  = ''
uri.query = nil
cleaned   = uri.to_s # http://foo.example.com:8080
```

Now you have your cleaned up version in `cleaned`. Taking out what you don't want is sometimes easier than only grabbing what you need.

If you only do `uri.query = ''` you'll end up with `http://foo.example.com:8080?` which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: And check `URI#split` for other types of information you may want to clear (or not), e.g. userinfo, fragment, ...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `uri.split()` and then put the parts back together...

WARNING: It's a little sloppy.

```
url = "http://example.com:9001/over-nine-thousand"
parts = uri.split(url)
puts "%s://%s:%s" % [parts[0], parts[2], parts[3]]

=> "http://example.com:9001"
```

Comment: Hmm, okay, and I could include the port too. [Documentation here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M009386)

Comment: There could be userinfo in the URL too. Yeah, I know, I'm being picky about pathological cases :)