# Redirect all break url to a specific method - In Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I just want to redirect all the break url to a specific method ..

Is there any short cut method for doing that ..

Someone help me find solution for this

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755919/ruby-rails-3-1-given-a-url-string-remove-path

Comment: if you could elaborate your question by code, then other can better help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails catch-all route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388715/rails-catch-all-route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duplicate question

[Rails catch-all route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388715/rails-catch-all-route)

> put
>
> match '*path' => 'your_controller#your_action' at the end of the
>   routes.rb file. This is important, since the routes are stepped
>   through top down.
>
> See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html -> 3.10

all routes that are not catched prior to this one will be dispatched to `your_controller#your_action`